# How to know without having iphone and ipad, any javascript/jquery effect/plugin will work on those?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, css, ipad

How to know without having iphone and ipad, any javascript/jquery effect/plugin which is working fine on all desktop browsers, will work on iphone and ipad also?

Is it enough to check on Latest Safari for Windows? I don't have MAC OSX .My os is Windows.

Answer (score 3):

While I know that jQuery works in the things I've tried with it on my sites, I do sometimes make sure by using an iPhone simulator. Try this on a Windows:

http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662

Mac users can use Xcode's iPhone Simulator.